# JavaScript - referencing a function (method) in a different class in ES6

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am hoping my explanation provides enough information and that the answer is simple.  This is for a project I have started recently and first exposure to JavaScript ES6 syntax.

We use RequireJS, and each page has two primary pages required: `reports/pages/common` and `reports/pages/settings_page`  I believe these pages are analogous somewhat to controllers in Angular (which I have a little experience with).

The code is transpiled by gulp.

My question is, how do I call (from a method inside `class SettingsPage`) a method in an instance of the `class CommonPage` class?  I do not know what the name of the `CommonPage` instance is but here is the script at the bottom, just before the </html> tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // always loading bootstrap to enable data attributes to work
    // only loading bootstrap once, see comment above.
    require(['bootstrap', 'babelPolyfill', 'reports/pages/common', 'reports/pages/settings_page'], function(bootstrap, babelPolyfill, common, page) {
        if ((window.fin) && (window.fin.pageInitArguments)) {
            page.init(window.fin.pageInitArguments);
        } else {
            page.init();
        }
        common.init();
    });
});
```

Comment: you reference the function by using  `instanceOfCommonPage.functionName` - where `instanceOfCommonPage` is ??? do you know?

Comment: That's the 64 thousand dollar question :)

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how do a reference (from a function inside class `SettingsPage`) a function in the class `CommonPage`?

It would be clearer if you used the term "method" instead of "function" here. I also presume when you say "reference a function in the class", you actually mean "call a method in the class on an instance of that class".

Well, an instance of a class is just a regular old object with methods sitting on its prototype. You call a method on such an object in the same way you have for years, by saying

```
object.method()
```